# Sourcegear-vault - the find in files option not working. How to fix it?

Tags: sourcegear-vault

I have been using Vault, and I am happy with it.

[image]

One thing that is missing for me though, is the ability to "find in files"

the option is available on the menu but it simply does not work.

> An error occurred in Find in Files. Server Error: [3000] - The
>   repository's index status is not currently enabled.

[image]

How can I enable the repository's index status, or whatever is needed in order to use the find in files option?

**This is what I have tried to do so far:**

> Find in Files needs to be set up for the repository.  Go to the Vault
>   admin web page (http:///vaultservice/admin), expand
>   the list of repositories on the left, and then expand the repository
>   name.  Click the Find in Files link.  Click the On radio button, and
>   then click Save on the right side.
>
> It takes time for the database for this feature to be built.  If you
>   refresh the page in a few minutes, you will see something next to the
>   words "Status Msg:".    Once the result says Ready, then Vault is
>   ready for Find in Files to be used.
>
> Very large databases can take a very long time.  Our internal database
>   took a full weekend to build.
>
> If the setting changes from On to Off, then the service has failed. 
>   If that happens, let me know and I'll provide further instructions

[image]

[image]

this is what I currently have on my IIS:

[image]